# Подгрузка изображений на сайте

Tags: php, css, html5, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой и решил отписать сюда, так как гугл мне не помог. Создал сайт на локалке всё работает как надо загрузил его на хостинг reg.ru всё работало как надо, но спустя некоторое время изображения находящиеся на главной странице сайта то загружаются то нет. В чем может быть проблема?? Вес изображений ужат до минимума и это не помогает. Css стили убираю тоже самое...Js убираю тоже самое...сломал голову уже..Прикрепляю фото[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: напишите ссылку на сайт

Comment: Что в логах сервера пишут? Что в консоли браузера в разделе сеть при открытии страницы?

Comment: ссылка https://www.flex-ment.pro/   .. пишут 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 429 () на картинку

Failed to parse SourceMap: https://www.flex-ment.pro/App/templates/css/bootstrap.min.css.map  на css

Comment: @Михаил, 429 ошибка - это Слишком много запросов: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#429 Вам надо не изображений сжимать, а уменьшить количество загружаемых объектов. Настройте кэширование статики, объедините js/css в один файл, мелкие  изображения либо соберите в спрайты, либо переведите их в base64 и пропишите прямо в css.

Comment: я использую gulp.. только не понимаю как это объединить js + css gulp поможет объединить?

Comment: Имел в виду: все js в один файл js, все css в один файл css.

Comment: пробовал scss в один файл..та же проблема...

Comment: Или ищите другой хостинг, или платите за нормальный план.

Comment: У openshift.com неплохой бесплатный план.